# A tag for questions like "what does this word \ phrase mean?"

Tags: discussion, tagging, tags

I think we need one more tag for questions like "Please help me understand the meaning of this word \ this phrase. I can't find a good translation in my dictionary"?  Or does it also goes under the tag "usage"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use a general one like [meaning](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning). I don't think we should use something more specific than that.

Comment: It seems that all other sites have "meaning" tag exactly for this purpose. I'd make such tag, too, but let's wait for other people to express their opinion.